# Reversing SVG Path Fill to Plain Text

Tags: html, svg

When looking through the source code of a local website I found a spot within it where instead of just outputting text they drew it with SVG and path fills.  I'd like to parse this SVG data and convert it to plain text.  I've seen many tutorials on how to convert text to SVG, but not the other way around.  Here is a snippet of what is on the site:

```
<path fill="#ffffff" d="m40.924747 11.631161l4.0 -0.234375q0.140625 1.015625.....
```

Obviously the browser is able to parse it and render the text so I should be able to, too.

Thank you for any pointers!

Comment: Your **brain** is able to parse it as text, for the computer, it's just a path. Now, there are some [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) algos that had been written in this purpose, you could learn it and use it. But your question is way too broad to have an answer here.

Comment: You mean like https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XMLSerializer